# *** glibc detected *** error from texmaker in tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

I am facing a very strange problem. Texmaker quits with an error under a very specific condition, which has nothing to do with compilation, but rather what I type. Say for a minimal working example, I start typing

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
```

If I now try to type `domain` I get to `do`, pressing `m` or any other character exits Texmaker with the following:

`*** glibc detected *** texmaker: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002d67de0 ***`

There are a lot more lines to it. Including these libraries: `libc.so.6`, `ibQtGui.so.4`, `libQtCore.so.4`, `libglib-2.0.so.0`

I don't recall having had this problem before and it seems to be a problem with the interface (Qt) I guess. I believe this will also work with other latex environments, not just `tikzpicture`, but haven't found any yet.

Using `\begin{tikzpicture}` makes the following lines appear orange. Typing `do` appears in blue as would `for`. It seems Texmaker recognizes that a code is to follow, or something of the sort. But it does not crash when typing `for`.

I am honestly lost as to how to fix this. Any ideas?

I am using:
Linux Mint 13 Maya MATE, Texmaker 3.2, Texlive 2012

Also: This only happens if `do` are the first characters on a new line.

Full error output [here](http://pastebin.com/bNA21nEZ)

**UPDATE**: The problem seems to be version specific. I installed Texmaker 3.3 and do not face this problem any more. I have also installed Texmaker 3.2 on another Linux machine and face the same error.

Comment: Interesting indeed. What happens if you paste the whole word directly?

Comment: copy/paste of the entire word works.

Comment: I don't know much about TeXmaker but is there any macro/plugin that tracks your input for auto-replace or something along those lines?